# Why do Hamiltonian simulation algorithms not depend on the size of the Hamiltonian for the gate complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, hamiltonian-simulation, oracles

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_simulation) for Hamiltonian simulation mentions the gate and query complexities for different algorithms used for the problem (Trotter-Suzuki, Taylor Series, Quantum Walks, and QSP).

They mention that if the Hamiltonian is given explicitly, the gate complexity matters *more* than the query complexity, and if $\hat{H}$ is given as an oracle, the query complexity matters more. I am not sure what to really make of this.

What I am taking away from this statement is this:

Suppose we are given some undirected graph whose adjacency matrix (or maybe even Laplacian matrix) represents a Hamiltonian. Simulating this Hamiltonian only depends on the Gate complexity.

Is this the case? If so, then why does the size of the graph not matter in the gate complexity?

I am referencing this

[image: Table of gate complexities from the wikipedia page]

The query complexities, however, depend on the $d$ term, which is the sparsity. This makes a bit more sense to me.

Is my premise wrong? Does query complexity actually matter when the Hamiltonian is given explicitly, like as a graph's adjacency matrix? If so, can someone give me a concrete explanation of why gate complexity matters *more* than query complexity in this case, and what that means?